# manually import snippet for gedit in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, gedit

I am trying to import a new snippet into snippet plugin for gedit.  But when i click on the 'import' button the screen freezes and am not able to click on the dialog.  I looked online for a solutin and found out that it is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit/+bug/193296) Looks like the bug is still not fixed as I am using ubuntu 9.04.

Does any one know how to import a snippet manually into gedit's snippet plugin?

Answer (score 2):

Snippets are stored globally in:

/usr/share/gedit-2/plugins/snippets/

or user specific in:

~/.gnome2/gedit/snippets

Comment: In Gedit 3, they are in `~/.config/gedit/snippets`